# Почему этот код работает медленно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Это мой первый скрипт, поэтому скорее всего тут куча идиотских решений. Его задача: открыть спрятанное меню при клике, затемнить некоторые элементы при открытом меню и точно также в другую сторону (+ при клике вне открытого меню). Есть также контактная форма (которая, кстати тоже не оч. корректно работает, но это другой вопрос), которая тоже появляется при клике на пункт меню и закрывается в случае клика на крестик (он тоже управляется этим скриптом). Меня раздражает дерганность процесса на боевом сервере. Хочется сделать лаконично и четко.

```
$(function() {
        var slideMenu = false;
        var slideForm = false;
        function removeOpen() {
            $("body, .face-page__title, .object__background-image, .footer, hr").removeClass('open');
            $(".logo-dark, .fb-dark, .vk-dark, .ins-dark").toggleClass('coverup');
            $(".logo, .fb, .vk, .ins").removeClass('coverup');
        }; 

        function addOpen() {
            $("body, .face-page__title, .object__background-image, .footer, hr").toggleClass('open');
            $(".logo, .fb, .vk, .ins").toggleClass('coverup');
            $(".logo-dark, .fb-dark, .vk-dark, .ins-dark").removeClass('coverup');
        }; 

        function formButton() {
            $( ".object__contact-form_activator" ).click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".object__contact-form").animate({left: '0vw'}, 200);
                slideForm = true;
            });
        };

        function menuButtonMobile() {
            $(".header__menu-button_icon").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(e);
                if(slideMenu) {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                    $(".object__menu-slide-box").animate({left: '161vw'}, 200);
                    $(".object__contact-form").animate({left: '-100vw'}, 200);
                    $(".header, .header.scroll").removeClass('open');
                    slideForm = false;
                    slideMenu = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).toggleClass('open');
                    $(".object__menu-slide-box").animate({left: '0'}, 200);
                    $(".header, .header.scroll").addClass('open');
                    slideMenu = true;
                }
            });
        };

        if ( $(window).width() >= 320 &  $(window).width() < 479) {
            menuButtonMobile();
            formButton();
        } else if ( $(window).width() > 375 & $(window).width() < 415) {
            menuButtonMobile();
            formButton();
        } else if ( $(window).width() > 416 & $(window).width() < 1199) {
            menuButtonMobile();
            formButton();
        } else if ( $(window).width() > 1200) {   
            $(".header__menu-button_icon").click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                if(slideMenu) {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                    $(".object__menu-slide-box").animate({left: '161vw'}, 200);
                    $(".object__contact-form").animate({left: '-61vw'}, 200);
                    $(".face-page__title_cases-menu, .face-page__title_cases-menu.fixed").removeClass('open');
                    removeOpen();
                    slideForm = false;
                    slideMenu = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).toggleClass('open');
                    $(".object__menu-slide-box").animate({left: '61vw'}, 200);
                    $(".face-page__title_cases-menu, .face-page__title_cases-menu.fixed").addClass('open');
                    addOpen();

                    slideMenu = true;
                }
            });
            formButton();
            $(window).click(function() {
                if(slideMenu && slideForm) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                } else if (slideMenu) {
                    $(".header__menu-button_icon").removeClass('open');
                    $(".object__menu-slide-box").animate({left: '161vw'}, 200);
                    $(".object__contact-form").animate({left: '-61vw'}, 200);
                    $(".face-page__title_cases-menu, .face-page__title_cases-menu.fixed").removeClass('open');
                    removeOpen();
                    slideMenu = false;
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: было бы здорово, если бы вы воспроизвели проблему на https://jsfiddle.net, к примеру

Comment: @Skywave зачем предлагать jsfiddle, если тут есть встроенные сниппеты, которые ничем не хуже?

Comment: @Skywave 
https://ilyagoncharov.github.io/julonew.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

1) Что бы удобнее было разбираться залейте на jsfiddle.net например.
2) У вас в коде довольно много подобных моментов

```
function menuButtonMobile() {
     $(".header__menu-button_icon").click(function(e) {}} ????
if ( $(window).width() > 1200) {   
     $(".header__menu-button_icon").click(function(e) {}} ????

function formButton() {
     $( ".object__contact-form_activator" ).click(function(e) {}} ????
```

Инициализацию обработки нажатий надо производить в $(document).ready, а не внутри функций и условий. Возможно в этом и проблема.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header__menu-button_icon").click(function(e) {
    // ваш код
    })

    $(".object__contact-form_activator" ).click(function(e) {
     // ваш код
    })
}
```

Comment: А разве это не то, что я сделал? 
По идее они должны хойститься же, ноу ..

Comment: по логике что происходит? Вы нажали 1 раз событие инициализировалось. Когда вы нажимаете второй раз довольно сложно предсказать работу. Ибо оно у вас и проходит инициализацию во второй раз и одновременно выполняет заданные действия по нажатию, которое инициализировалось в первый раз. Думаю именно из за этого у вас происходит "дерганность". т.к. события "дерутся" друг с другом.
"А разве это не то, что я сделал?". Нет не то, в том примере, котором я показал - происходит инициализация событий, после того как документ будет готов. И при нажатии отрабатывают.

Comment: Силюсь понять. Сейчас порядок таков: 1) шорткод для $(document).ready(function() 2) задекларировал все функции и переменные (разве это не инициализация?) 3) // объясняю, при каких условиях нужно это применить

Comment: Силюсь объяснить) У вас проблемы начинаются на втором пункте. Функции то вы объявили действительно, но работу в них(т.е. нажатие на такой, то элемент - не объявили); 3) После нажатия у вас они объявляются.
З.ы. вы пытаетесь объединить 2 метода обработки событий. Вы либо из $( ".object__contact-form_activator" ).click(function(e) {}}  вытаскивайте весь функционал в функцию. Либо вытаскивайте саму обработку $( ".object__contact-form_activator" ).click(function(e) {}} из объявленных функций.

Comment: к вашему совету прислушался, код поправил. Проблема не ушла. Только когда я убрал все мелкие анимации (там, где я добавляю классы coverup и open) проблема решилась. Как бы реализовать эти анимации другим путем, чтобы не вернулся глитч ощущений этот. Пока в загадках